# Maven compilation : bad operand types for binary operator '>>'

Tags: maven

At `mvn compile`, maven says :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: bad operand types for binary operator '>>'
```

... but I don't use >> in my code ??

Until now, the compilation was ok.

I just go from java 6 to java 7.

My mvn version is :

```
/home/herve> mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
Maven home: /home/herve/apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.7.0_03, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/herve/jdk1.7.0_03/jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.0-16-generic-pae", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Thanks for your help.

---

edit :

Here is the pom config of compiler :

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      <compilerArgument>-deprecation</compilerArgument>
      <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

... and best of all there's no error in my code.

Comment: Have you configured compiler plugin to use java 7? Also, what happens if you invoke `javac` on this particular file?

Comment: How about posting the offending line/area of the code?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question to show the compiler config. There is NO error is my code, so I can't posting or javac the particular file. Thanks to you.

Comment: FIND ! It was a mic-mac with lombock. I don't know what exactly, but if I suppress lombock, all work perfect. Planty thanks to all.